# node / express response.redirect not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

so , i'm trying to redirect to some homepage after a user logs in to the site correctly , 
i'll give more details through the code :

after clicking a button , a function gets called and sends a post request to API (using angularJS ) , this part works properly :

```
$scope.login = function () {
        console.log("logging in ... ") ;
        $http.post('api/login', $scope.Ldata) // Ldata id form data that will get checked by server 
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data) ;
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                 console.log(err) ;
            }) ;
    } ;
```

and in API :

```
app.post('/api/login' , function (req , res) {
    Todo.findOne( { email : req.body.mail } , function (err, user) {
        if (err) { res.send(err) ; }
        if (user) {
            if (user.password !== req.body.pass ) {
                console.log("wrong password ") ;
                res.send(err) ;
            }
             else {
                //everything ok ...
                console.log("write to session ") ;
                req.session.user = user.email ;
                res.send('go to home') ;
                res.redirect('/home') ;
            }
        }
    })
}) ;
```

again , everything works fine , session will get updated AND , i do get a new GET request to /home in my terminal where i ran the server file with node , but , the page won't actually get redirected ..

can someone help me out here ? i'm new to all these node stuff and i have this feeling that i'm just making a silly mistake here that i can't see .. 
thanks .

Comment: Did you try commenting out `res.send('go to home') ;` ?

Comment: @mscdex nope , still not redirecting ( but i read somewhere that nothing after res.send() will get executed because send() also closes() the resp object )

Comment: you're doing an ajax request to the login endpoint, so in your success function of the post your `data` variable will hold the contents of whatever gets returned, the browser won't go anywhere.

Comment: and another thing to notice and i do not know why it happens is that i do get the entire html code of my /home in browser console ..

Comment: @mrObrian good points , and you're right i suppose , let me change the question , how Do i Do that ( actually redirecting ) ? :) i could fill the address as <form> action attribute or ...

Comment: you could have the server return the path that the browser should go to as a string and in your success function set the window's location to that string

Comment: worked , thanks , and if anyone else have a different idea , i'll be glad to hear ( cause i think there could be many more ways to do this )